# Is it possible to open the certain fragment in sliding tabs?

Tags: android, fragment

I have in my application two lists of messages, incoming and outgoing. These two lists are placed on the fragments, which in turn are in SlidingTab. And so it turns out that when you open a screen with these tabs, two requests from fragments are always sent to receive two lists of messages. But I need something to activate the fragment only when selecting the appropriate tab. Because when my access_token dies, I have two requests for a token update request, and one of the requests must return an error from the server.

### UPD:

logs of my error:

```
08-16 16:16:24.135 E: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.developer_4.test_login, PID: 10852
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
        at com.example.developer_4.test_login.Tabs.Sent.sent(Sent.java:92)
        at com.example.developer_4.test_login.Tabs.Sent.setUserVisibleHint(Sent.java:70)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:160)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1234)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
        at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:95)
        at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1556)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:803)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:689)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2275)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1366)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1619)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

line 92:

```
access_token = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSharedPreferences(ACCESS_TOKEN, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

line 70:

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            sent(); - line 70
        }
    }
```

Help please solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `setUserVisibleHint` in your fragment and make API calls when your fragment is visible.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        //make Api Call here
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
   private boolean isVisible;
   private boolean isStarted;

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        isStarted = true;
        if (isVisible){
            //make Api Call here
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        isStarted = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        isVisible = isVisibleToUser;
        if (isVisible && isStarted){
            //make Api Call here
        }
    }
```

Comment: as I understand it, your method will allow you to send a request only when the tab is in focus? I tried the solution from your answer, and I had everything working as needed, but I had an error that caused the application to crash

Comment: Your edits did not change the situation, the application still fell